# Python and the imports

Tags: python, package

I have a python project where I use grpc.
I create the files with `python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I "pathToMyProtoFile" --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. "pathToMyProtoFile\module.proto"`

I want all the grpc-stuff to be in a python package. So I created a sub folder "my_package_folder" and added an empty `__init__.py` in it.

My Problem: How to access and where to place the generated `module_pb2.py` and `module_pb2_grpc.py`.

If I place them into the root folder of my application I cannot access them from my package with `from .. import module_pb2_grpc` "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

If I place them into my "my_package_folder" the 2 generated files do not find each other.
(`import module_pb2 as module__pb2` in "module_pb2_grpc.py")

This import mechanism in python is so extremely confusing... I have no idea where to start to solve this problem.

My folder structure is just the main project folder and a sub folder "my_package_folder" for all the grpc stuff.

Comment: Could you add your current folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a folder structure like this. I'm just taking the example of one file.

```
├── module_pb2_grpc.py
├── my_package_folder
│   ├── __init__.py
```

Then to resolve the `attempted relative import beyond top-level package`, you can add this.

****init**.py**

```
import os
import sys
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
from module_pb2_grpc import *
```

Comment: This solution works. I would never have guessed that this is the standard way.